JPA @Procedure call throwing Unable to commit against JDBC Connection Exception
I have a springboot app which runs a stored procedure which was running fine but this procedure call started throwing exception when we upgraded the other sql database in which this app makes multi db connections, the strange this is this stored proc seems to be in the other db which infact not updated but the other one did.
Not really sure whats causing this error. Here is how the entities defined
public interface UpdateStatusFlagRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Procedure(name = "updateStatusFlags")
    void updateStatusFlagToN();
}

Below is the Entity
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "dbo.employee")
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "updateStatusFlags",
        procedureName = "dbo.st_upd_status_flag_rec"
)
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private String employeeId;

    @Column(name = "company")
    private String company;

}

I was able to fix this error by placing
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit=true

After placing the above in application properties error stopped displaying, but not sure whether this does make the transactions but not really sure what caused to throw this error
Below is the stack trace for this error
[2024-08-29 20:01:48.758] [cmp.server.com] [main] INFO c.w.o.service.UpdateStatusFlagService@updateStatusFlagToN:17 - updateStatusFlagToN() is being called
[2024-08-29 20:01:48.883] [cmp.server.com] [main] INFO o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener@logMessage:136 - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2024-08-29 20:01:48.887] [cmp.server.com] [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication@reportFailure:826 - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.win.ordershipecmupdateservice.OrderShipEcmupdateServiceApplication.main(OrderShipEcmupdateServiceApplication.java:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:538)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:631)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.updateBillpayEBPFlagToN(Unknown Source)
    at com.win.ordershipecmupdateservice.service.UpdateStatusFlagService.updateStatusFlagToN(UpdateEBPFlagService.java:18)
    at com.win.ordershipecmupdateservice.service.FlagUpdateService.run(FlagUpdateService.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to commit against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:54800000001.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:283)

